# XCode 15 #Preview Macro on multiple devices

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode15, swift-macro

I couldn't find a way to preview my `SwiftUI` views on multiple devices using the new `XCode 15`'s `#Preview` macro.
It was working with `XCode 14` and was showing side-by-side previews on the canvas, each preview with the correct target device, but it's not the case with `XCode 15`, here's my code to do that:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .previewOnDevices()
}

//#Preview {
//    ContentView()
//        .previewOnDevices()
//}

extension View {
    func previewOnDevices() -> some View {
        ForEach(DeviceName.all, id: \.self) { devicesName in
                previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: devicesName))
                .previewDisplayName(devicesName)
        }
    }
}

enum DeviceName: String, CaseIterable {
    //xcrun simctl list devicetypes
    case iPhoneSE = "iPhone SE (3rd generation)"
    case iPhone13Mini = "iPhone 13 mini"

    static var all: [String] {
        return DeviceName.allCases.map { $0.rawValue }
    }
}
```

and the result is the same view repeated:

[image]

I am aware that I can choose any device I want from the devices list in the canvas but this shows me one device at a time, meaning that I need to choose the desired device each time I need it which's a headache, even if I have multiple #Previews, `XCode` sticks for the chosen device in the canvas among `#Preview` previews.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm fighting with this too.. no luck. Have you found a solution maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried many things and done extensive research.
Here's my final conclusion: as of Xcode 15.1, there's no way to accomplish this using a `#Preview` macro.
You can find a similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77386048/1823922.

In my view, this limitation likely exists for performance reasons. Currently, I've set up previews using the say old `PreviewProvider` method with three devices:

- 6.7 (15 Pro Max)
- 6.5 (11 Pro Max)
- 5.5 (8 Plus)

As result, I've noticed a much longer loading times when switching between previews and SwiftUI views specially.

Anyway, it can be done, but only like this:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewOnDevices()
    }
}
```